# Unable to detect back press button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onbackpressed

I have viewpager with couple of fragments inside. I need to get confirmation when user presses back button. However, it doesn't get called unless I visit last page.

```
public class Create_Safety_CheckList_MainFragment extends Fragment
        implements View.OnClickListener, Observer {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_safety_checklist_pager_main, container, false);
        initializeUI();

        return view;
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        setHeader(getResources().getString(R.string.safety_check_list_checklist_screen_name));
        addFragments();
        mPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_home_screen_activity);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(fragmentArrayList.size());
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(onPageChangeListener);
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
//        mPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
//
//            @Override
//            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
//                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
//                return false;
//            }
//        });


        customTextViewChecklistName = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_New_Checklist_Name);
        if (createChecklistObservationModel.getChecklistName() != null)
            customTextViewChecklistName.setText(createChecklistObservationModel.getChecklistName());

    }

    private void addFragments() {
        createChecklistAdditionalTabFragment = new CreateChecklistAdditionalTabFragment();
        fragmentArrayList.add(createChecklistAdditionalTabFragment);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            if (bundle.containsKey("***")) {
                String response = spcl_databaseHandler.getSpecificChecklistAdditionals(bundle.getString("checklistID"));
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject dataJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Data");

                    JSONArray checkListAdditionalFieldDtoJsonArray = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("***");
                    int additionalsLength = checkListAdditionalFieldDtoJsonArray.length();
                    if (additionalsLength > 0) {
dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("***").toString());
                        additionalInfoFragment = new Additional_Information_Fragment();
                        fragmentArrayList.add(additionalInfoFragment);
                    }

                    JSONArray jsonGroupsArray = dataJsonObject.getJSONArray("***");
                    int groupsLength = jsonGroupsArray.length();
                    for (int i = 0; i < groupsLength; i++) {
                        JSONObject groupJsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonGroupsArray.get(i);
                        JSONArray questionsJsonArray = groupJsonObject.getJSONArray("Questions");
                        int questionsLength = questionsJsonArray.length();
                        for (int j = 0; j < questionsLength; j++) {
                            checklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment = new ChecklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment();
                            checklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment.setArguments(bundle1);
                            fragmentArrayList.add(checklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment);
                        }

                        JSONArray subGroupsJsonArray = groupJsonObject.getJSONArray("SubGroups");
                        int subGroupsJsonArrayLength = subGroupsJsonArray.length();
                        for (int j = 0; j < subGroupsJsonArrayLength; j++) {
                            JSONObject subGroupObject = subGroupsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
                            JSONArray subGroupQuestionsJsonArray = subGroupObject.getJSONArray("Questions");
                            int subGroupQuestionsJsonArrayLength = subGroupQuestionsJsonArray.length();
                            for (int k = 0; k < subGroupQuestionsJsonArrayLength; k++) {
checklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment = new ChecklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment();                                fragmentArrayList.add(checklistGroupsDiscussionQuestionOneFragment);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        questionsFragment = new Other_Questions_Fragment();
        membersFragment = new Inspection_Members_Fragment();

        fragmentArrayList.add(questionsFragment);
        fragmentArrayList.add(membersFragment);
    }

    private void setHeader(String headerTitle) {
    }

    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener onPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int pageNumber, float positionOffset,
                                   int positionOffsetPixels) {
//            mPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            showArrows(pageNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageView_Next:
                break;

            case R.id.imageView_Previous:
                break;

            case R.id.textView_Cancel :
                callToCloseDialog();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void callToCloseDialog() {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
            return;
        }
        mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_dialog_message))
                .setTitle("Warning");

        builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_dialog_yes_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(getResources().getString(R.string.new_checklist_fragment), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.cancel_dialog_no_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked cancel button
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object o) {
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 3 objects, in sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragmentArrayList.size();
        }
    }

    private void showArrows(int pageNumber) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                callToCloseDialog();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(QuestionResponsesModel questionResponsesModel){
    }

}
```

Kept only code for Viewpager & fragments loading.

Comment: You need to create interface for this.Because Your activity back pressed called not your fragment so you need to create interface which implements in your fragment. hope this helps you.

Comment: But I can get it here as well only thing is unless I visit last page it doesn't detect dialog open call.

Answer (score 1):

**By Default `Fragment` Don't have any back Pressed event, so you have to manage it by `Activity` `onBackPressed()` method using below code.**

Override `onBackPressed()` method in your Activity and Apply Check for it.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      // put condition here
        if("Your Fragment is Visible"){
           //Apply confirmation check here 
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question

Comment: i have understand this, you have to prevent  back press till last fragment in not get visible.... in simple word you want to fire back  press only from Last fragment of your View Pager. is am Right?

Comment: can you explain me with any example like?

Comment: This answer looks correct to me. Catch the back button on the Activity, and determine with fragment is currently showing. Then act accordingly. Or pass through the backbutton click to the a fragment method that handles it

Answer (score 0):

You can override this method in activity and listen backpress

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        ...
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) 
        {
            int action = event.getAction();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            switch (keyCode) 
            {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        Log.v("myApp", "Back button pressed.");
                        return true;
                    }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```